# Extend a sequence of functions which is not convergent in any point in $[0,1]$ to functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with the same property

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence of intervals $(J_n)$ given by
$$
[0,1],[0,\tfrac{1}{2}],[\tfrac{1}{2},1],[0,\tfrac{1}{3}],[\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{2}{3}],[\tfrac{2}{3},1],[0,\tfrac{1}{4}], \ldots
$$
Defining $Y_n := \chi_{J_n}$  gives us a sequence of functions $Y_n : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $Y_n$ converges to $0$ in measure but $\lim_{n \to \infty} Y_n(x)$ does not exist for any $x \in [0,1]$. Can one extend $Y_n$ to a function $X_n : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $X_n$ still converges to $0$ in measure but $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n(x)$ does not exist for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, consider the following sequence of intervals:
$$[-1, -\tfrac{1}{2}], [-\tfrac{1}{2}, 0], [0, \tfrac{1}{2}], [\tfrac{1}{2}, 1]\\
[-2, -2 + \tfrac{1}{3}],[-2 + \tfrac{1}{3}, -2 + \tfrac{2}{3}], \ldots, [2 - \tfrac{1}{3}, 2] \\
[-3, -3+\tfrac{1}{4}],[-3 + \tfrac{1}{4}, -3 + \tfrac{2}{4}],  \ldots, [3 - \tfrac{1}{4}, 3] \\ \ldots$$

It is difficult to write this sequence down precisely, but I hope it is clear how the construction works.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of $n$ intervals with width $1/n$, consider having $n^2$ of them, so that the last interval keeps covering larger and larger numbers. That should extend the domain to $\mathbb R ^+$.